# Polite rejection from adviser

Tags: graduate-admissions, interview

I am a latinamerican student and I am not sure about the responses from potential PhD adviser email responses, I had a very nice interview with one of them who told me that he enjoyed our conversation ( our interview) two days later he wrote me an email in which he said that " I enjoyed our conversation a lot" and that he decided on aother candidate. He also said " be assure that you did an excellent job I just simply had to make a decision"

Is this genuine ? or a polite way to reject me?  I would prefer the truth from a PhD adviser in order to improve other interviews!

In my Country too much politness is not used

Thanks in advance

Comment: How could anyone know the answer to this, except the supervisor himself? In your place I'd assume that he was telling the truth: that I was a good candidate, but that there had been a better candidate who got the position. It's not an uncommon situation, after all.

Comment: I'm not sure if the potential advisor was American, but if so this may be relevant: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38177/how-do-you-know-if-americans-genuinely-literally-mean-what-they-say

Comment: He is  from Germany

Comment: @user75169 In that case he was almost certainly sincere. If you do badly, it is very acceptable in Germany to just tell it to your face.

Comment: thanks!! It is a shame since I really wanted to work this adviser. :(

Comment: There are years when there is a whole bunch of capable people competing for the same position. Then, you may be very good, but superseded by somebody even better. In other years, you would have made it with flying colours.

Comment: It would be still possible to have him back?

Comment: @sgf No, not in a situation where it could lead to legal problems. You are not supposed to give a candidate the actual reason for rejecting their application. This is almost certainly a boilerplate rejection message.

Comment: @Roland But does saying "I didn't take you because you're too bad at X, Y and Z" lead to legal problems?

Comment: @sgf Nowadays that's hard to judge for the legal layman. Thus, our administration tells us to say nothing beyond that someone else was a better fit.

Comment: My questions was based on the fact that if I can obtain my own funding, to ask him to join to his lab since I am very interested in his research. However, if this was a generic response, I do not think he is truly honest.

Answer (score 0):

"I enjoyed our conversation a lot" is a standard phrase and doesn't mean very much. The added "...excellent job..." probably means just that, unfortunately sometimes you get more than one good candidate and he's acknowledging that fact.